# Chain optionals with void return type

Tags: java, spring

JDK 8:

I'm validating input request. Is there a way to nicely chain these optionals? Or some other way to make it look a bit nicer and get rid off too many if optional checks? kinda looks ugly.

In REST controller class:

```
{
   ...

   Optional<ResponseEntity<?>> operationError = requestValidator.handleOperationError(bodyParams, myHandler, serviceInstance, null);
    if( operationError.isPresent()){
        return operationError.get();
    }

    Optional<ResponseEntity<?>> otherError = requestValidator.checkRequestOther(serviceInstance, bodyParams, instanceAction);
    if( otherError.isPresent()){
        return otherError.get();
    }

    Optional<ResponseEntity<?>> someWeirdError = requestValidator.checksomeWeird(serviceInstance, instanceAction);
    if( someWeirdError.isPresent()){
        return someWeirdError.get();
    }

    Optional<ResponseEntity<?>> conflictError = requestValidator.conflictExists(instanceAction,serviceInstance);
    if( conflictError.isPresent()){
        return conflictError.get();
    }

   //If All fine start doing business logic
}
```

Comment: Maybe use some implementation of `org.springframework.validation.Error`  ?

Comment: 2 things: the ugliness isn't coming from the Optionals, it's from all the side-effect-infested code around the Optionals. and the point of chaining with flatMaps is to pass a boxed value through a series of function calls, where these are 4 distinct things, it's not as easy as "flatMap this @#$%". so this is not going to get pretty.

Comment: @Nathan Hughes thx. agreed, could you show a better design than using optionals? maybe some code samples?

Comment: no this is just to say you may need to lower your expectations. existing answers may be as good as it gets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a strict Java 8 solution, you can create an helper class:

```
public class OptionalHelper {

    public static <T> Optional<T> findFirstPresent(Supplier<Optional<T>>... optionals) {
        return Arrays.stream(optionals)
                .map(Supplier::get)
                .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(Optional.empty());
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
    Optional<ResponseEntity<?>> validationError = OptionalHelper.findFirstPresent(
            () -> requestValidator.handleOperationError(bodyParams, myHandler, serviceInstance, null),
            () -> requestValidator.checkRequestOther(serviceInstance, bodyParams, instanceAction),
            () -> requestValidator.checkSomeWeird(serviceInstance, instanceAction),
            () -> requestValidator.conflictExists(instanceAction, serviceInstance));

    if (validationError.isPresent()) {
        return validationError.get();
    }
```

Comment: to double check, this will NOT execute all statements before returning. correct?

Comment: @Spring, no, this will execute until first non-empty `Optional` is returned from a `Supplier` (I've talked about this exact appriach in comment under another answer here). And you can drom `sequential()` call, `Arrays.stream()` already creates sequential stream, there's a separate `parallelStream` for non-sequential streams.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Thanks for the details. Answer updated.

Comment: @Spring For the error `incompatible equality constraint` I think you must change the signature of `checkSome409()` to return `Optional<ResponseEntity<?>>` instead of `Optional<ResponseEntity<String>>`

Comment: @Benoit Is there any advantage using a flatmap over map here in your example? I see many examples using flatmap. thx

Comment: @Spring Yes I think you could replace the last line `orElse(Optional.empty())` with this one `flatMap(Function.identity())`. But IMHO it's less readable.

Answer (score 3):

I'm just going to start by saying: cleanest solution would require a better abstraction than `Optional` provides, because it's main purpose is to represent a missing value, not validation output.

However, what you want to achieve is still possible with use of `Optional::or` added since JDK 9:

```
Optional<ResponseEntity<?>> validationError = 
    requestValidator.handleOperationError(bodyParams, myHandler, serviceInstance, null)
    .or(() -> requestValidator.checkRequestOther(serviceInstance, bodyParams, instanceAction))
    .or(() -> requestValidator.checkSomeWeird(serviceInstance, instanceAction))
    .or(() -> requestValidator.conflictExists(instanceAction,serviceInstance));
if( validationError.isPresent() ){
    return validationError.get();
}
```

If you can't use Java 9, you will have to roll your own type, something like this:

```
public final class Error<T> {
    private T value;

    private Error(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static Error withValue(T value) {
        requireNonNull(value);
        return new Error(value);
    }

    public static <T> Error<T> start() {
        return new Error(null);
    }

    public static <T> Error<T> startWith(Supplier<T> firstCheck) {
        requireNonNull(firstCheck);
        return new Error(firstCheck.get());
    }

    public Error<T> thenCheck(Supplier<Error<? extends T>> nextCheck) {
        requireNonNull(nextCheck);

        return isPresent() ? this : requireNonNull(nextCheck.get());
    }

    public boolean isPresent() {
        return value != null;
    }

    public T get() {
        return value; // I think no need to be particularly fancy here, null means "No Error"
    }
}
```

Then, assuming your validator now returns `Error` instances:

```
Error<ResponseEntity<?>> validationError = 
    requestValidator.handleOperationError(...)
    .thenCheck(() -> requestValidator.checkRequestOther(...))
    .thenCheck(() -> requestValidator.checkSomeWeird(...))
    .thenCheck(() -> requestValidator.conflictExists(...));
if (validationError.isPresent()) {
    return validationError.get();
}
```

Comment: thx. I should have mentioned its JDK 8. How would you improve abstraction here?

Comment: @Spring, you need a "reverse-optional" that has a Unit (starts at) of `null` value, and changes its value exactly once to something non-null (by accepting a `Supplier`). There also might be a `flatMap` which always prefers first filled object (and is a no-op if current instance is filled).

Comment: sounds good ! though that would be perfect if you could point me to code samples.

Comment: @Spring, I've added a sample error container that implements what I was talking about.

Comment: your answer is very insightful. And probably will be helpful in other occasions. For my problem I have chosen the Benoit's answer, since its is simpler

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can chain the `Optional` values in a `Stream`, but I would only do this if getting the `Optional`s is inexpensive, as they are all evaluated even when the first one is present:

```
Optional<ResponseEntity<?>> operationError = 
    requestValidator.handleOperationError(bodyParams, myHandler, serviceInstance, null);
Optional<ResponseEntity<?>> otherError = 
    requestValidator.checkRequestOther(serviceInstance, bodyParams, instanceAction);
Optional<ResponseEntity<String>> some409Error = 
    requestValidator.checkSome409(serviceInstance, instanceAction);
Optional<ResponseEntity<?>> conflictError = 
    requestValidator.conflictExists(instanceAction,serviceInstance);

Optional<ResponseEntity<String>> anyError = 
    Stream.of(operationError, otherError, some409Error, conflictError)
          .filter(Optional.isPresent)
          .map(Optional::get)
          .findFirst();

if (anyError.isPresent) {
    return anyError.get();
}
```

---

A Java 8 Solution that evaluates lazily:

```
@SafeVarargs
public static <E> Optional<E> any(final Supplier<Optional<E>>... optionalSuppliers) {
    return Stream.of(optionalSuppliers)
                 .map(Supplier::get)
                 .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                 .map(Optional::get)
                 .findFirst();
}
```

And the callsite:

```
Optional<ResponseEntity<?>> anyError = any(
    () -> requestValidator.handleOperationError(bodyParams, myHandler, serviceInstance, null),
    () -> requestValidator.checkRequestOther(serviceInstance, bodyParams, instanceAction),
    () -> requestValidator.checkSome409(serviceInstance, instanceAction),
    () -> requestValidator.conflictExists(instanceAction, serviceInstance)
);

if (anyError.isPresent) {
    return anyError.get();
}
```

Comment: thanks but thats not my case, I should stop execution immediately and return

Comment: @Spring I would go with M. Prokhorovs solution then. It is preferable anyhow. I was not aware of `Optional::or`

Comment: Curious why they are all evaluated even you say findFirst()?

Comment: @Spring, because they are evaluated when you create the `Optional`, so before it has anything to do with a stream. To get it evaluate lazily with a stream, you need a `Stream<Supplier<Optional<?>>`, with a `map(Supplier::get).filter(Optional::isPresent)`.

Comment: @Spring see my updated answer for a solution that evaluates lazily and works in Java 8.